# Summing only distinct values in group by

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Region   State  Volume   Hour   Price
South    GA     23       1      35
South    GA     23       2      50
South    FL     35       3      60
South    FL     35       4      22
```

The same region, state will always have the save volume. What I'd like to do is sum up the distinct volume for the entire region. So for example, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Region   State  Volume   Hour   Price  TotalVolumeInRegion
South    GA     23       1      35     58
South    GA     23       2      50     58
South    FL     35       3      60     58
South    FL     35       4      22     58
```

Notice how we only add up 23 + 35. How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As distinct window functions are not supported, we can do this with a join.

```
val df = Seq(
  ("South", "GA", 23, 1, 35),
  ("South", "GA", 23, 2, 50),
  ("South", "FL", 35, 3, 60),
  ("South", "FL", 35, 4, 22)
).toDF("Region", "State", "Volume", "Hour", "Price")

val totals = df
  .select($"Region", $"State", $"Volume")
  .distinct()
  .groupBy($"Region")
  .agg(sum($"Volume") as "TotalVolumeInRegion")

df.join(totals, usingColumn = "Region").show()
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+------+----+-----+-------------------+
|Region|State|Volume|Hour|Price|TotalVolumeInRegion|
+------+-----+------+----+-----+-------------------+
| South|   GA|    23|   1|   35|                 58|
| South|   GA|    23|   2|   50|                 58|
| South|   FL|    35|   3|   60|                 58|
| South|   FL|    35|   4|   22|                 58|
+------+-----+------+----+-----+-------------------+
```